# how are programs able to verify an encrypted file's password?

Tags: c++, encryption, passwords, winzip

- consider (for an example) that we have encrypted a file (sample.txt) using win-zip 9 by typing a password "agoodpassword".
- now if we try to open the file by typing some wrong password, we get a error message saying: the password typed is incorrect.

**the question:**

how can a software verify if the password typed in is correct or not? the content of the file could be any random data, so checking for errors in the file after decryption is not going to work. But still the software needs some source to verify this password; so how does this win-zip software verify if the decryption is successful or not?

What I suspect is the password could also be there in the same file being encrypted. Is it true or does the software adopt any other method?

Comment: Don't write an encryption algorithm yourself unless its for learning purposes. I you want to do this, you might want to implement RSA:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)

Comment: yes it is for learning purpose; thanks.

Comment: I've removed the overly broad question about developing encryption software. It's not concise and it adds a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of just encrypting, many applications that create a ciphertext also create an authentication tag. This authentication tag can be checked before decryption; if the authentication tag is incorrect than one of the parameters (key, IV or ciphertext) is incorrect.

To use encryption using a password it is common to utilize PKCS#5 (password based encryption).  PKCS#5 contains a password hashing method that utilizes "key stretching", making it harder for an attacker to test/compare many passwords using brute force or dictionary attacks. Such a password hashing method is called a Password Based Key Derivation Function or PBKDF. The latest PKCS#5 describes PBKDF2.

Now if you want to create a new password based encryption method, I would propose to do the following:

1. Perform a PBKDF2 with (very) high iteration count and 128 bit salt;
2. Make sure that the user gets feedback about the strength of the password;
3. Perform a KBKDF (key based key derivation function) on the result of PBKDF2, creating a check value, a data encryption key, and a data authentication key;
4. Use the data encryption key for an encryption method, say AES-128-CBC with random IV;
5. Use the data authentication key for a HMAC over *the IV* and the ciphertext;
6. Store the check value;

To verify the correct password during decryption, use the check value.

Note that I did not discuss the KBKDF yet. You may use a hash over the output of the PBKDF2 and a simple counter or string for that, say `SHA-256(key seed, "ENC")`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a hash value to provide a very high probability that anything other than the correct password will be rejected.  Basically, if you hash a password it produces a number with a certain number of binary digits, and a good cryptographic hash will produce a completely different number (in as much as random thing *tend* to differ) if you type something even the tiniest bit different (for example, changing the order of two characters, or using uppercase instead of lower).

There's still a very small chance that two different passwords will produce the same hash value... for example if you only had a 32-bit hash value then there's about a 1 in 2^32 (4 billion) chance.  It gets quite mathematically complex to create a hash function that doesn't let you retrieve the password (especially if it is a short password, and someone can pre-generate a list of short words with specific hash values too), so you probably want to have a pretty weak hash - just good enough to avoid returning corrupt data for 99.99% of typos - and/or one that's known to be resistant to such attacks.

Comment: -1 for that last sentence (and I don't know how to fix it either). Why would you want a pretty weak hash? What about PBKDF's?

Comment: @owlstead: say you have a 8 byte hash of an 8 byte password, and the hash simplies copies the input - that's a "perfect" hash in the sense of no collisions, but obviously useless for this purpose.  You either want a weaker hash (e.g. 2 to 4 bytes) that doesn't capture so much about the password, or a harder-to-reverse hash.  As for PBKDFs - see " and/or one that's known to be resistant to such attacks"

Comment: Ah, I see now, that's actually a good way to proceed. But note that a strong hash is not enough, you need a PBKDF2 (which has more inputs, such as salts, compared to a hash). Furthermore, I'm not so sure that a weak hash cannot be used to rule out 99% of the passwords in a brute force attack, before decryption (!)

Comment: @owlstead: from my non-security-specialist / computing-science perspective, I've considered PBKDF2 to be a way to create a even-stronger hash from an already pretty-good one, rather than something distinct, but anyway I agree PBKDF2 is useful here.  Re weak hashes ruling out passwords, sure - if they're also quick to calculate.  Anyway - your answer is more comprehensive than mine, but the question just seems to be after the high-level concept and is asking about winzip - I don't know how zip encryption's changed recently but it used to be famously easy to crack....

Comment: Hmm, your answer is more what current software may do, mine is more how it should work. I'll +1 your answer, as long as we agree that there are security issues with the answer.

Comment: @owlstead: sounds about right... +1 from me too.  Cheers.